# Cannot add desktop entry for IntelliJ Community IDE on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

When I am viewing tutorials on installing IntelliJ IDE on Ubuntu, part of the install allows users to click an 'add desktop entry' button during the setup process. I don't get this option and don't see how you can do this post install. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

T

Comment: When you install _IntelliJ IDEA_ with **snap**, it automatically creates a desktop entry and hides _Create Desktop Entry_ in _Tools_ menu.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Standalone installation﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installation-guide.html#standalone) documentation for the Linux section:

To create a desktop entry, do one of the following:

- On the Welcome screen, click Configure | Create Desktop Entry

or

- From the main menu, click Tools | Create Desktop Entry